# No data being returned to view

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, adfs

HomeController

```
[ValidateInput(false)]
public ActionResult Index()
{
    FormsAuthentication.SignOut();
    Session.Clear();
    Session.Abandon();
    EmployeeViewModel evm = new EmployeeViewModel();
    ViewBag.wresult = Request.Form["wresult"];
    if (!string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(Request.Form["wresult"]))
    {
        XmlDocument wresult = new XmlDocument();
        wresult.LoadXml(Request.Form["wresult"]);
        XmlNodeList elemList = wresult.GetElementsByTagName("saml:Attribute");
        foreach (XmlNode node in elemList)
        {
            foreach (XmlAttribute attr in node.Attributes)
            {
                if (attr.Name.Equals("AttributeName") && attr.Value.Equals("emailaddress"))
                {
                    XmlNode child = node.FirstChild;
                    evm.EmployeeEmailId = child.InnerText;
                }
            }
        }
    }
    var emp = empModel.Get(evm.EmployeeEmailId);
    if (condition)
    {
        return RedirectToAction("Index", "XYZ", new { area = "PQR" });
    }
    return View("Test", evm)
}
```

The data that I am storing in the ViewBag here, as well as the object being returned with the view are returning blanks. I am unable to understand why this is.

evm object gets populated during the XML Processing, and there are some DB actions that happen to add more details to the object.

Comment: you are passing evm as a parameter,  but its not populated with any data

Comment: @DylanKilkenny no. evm gets populated during the XML Processing, and there are some DB actions that happen to add more details to the object. But even so, the ViewBag is also empty, which cannot be possible

Comment: Request.Form is actually data from an ADFS.

Comment: Usually, when using ADFS, you have a local federation service running on your server and the web application reads the authentication information from cookies. Are you sure you want to read the authentication information from a form and not from cookies?

Comment: @NineBerry I will need to do a little more research into this. I seem have taken this up with very little knowledge. Thank you

Comment: @Sanketh.K.Jain With using asp.net mvc, you have built-in support for ADFS. Usually, you don't have to write any code, but just make some configuration, see for example http://www.cloudidentity.com/blog/2014/02/12/use-the-on-premises-organizational-authentication-option-adfs-with-asp-net-in-visual-studio-2013/

Answer (score 0):

`EmployeeViewModel evm = new EmployeeViewModel();`

This is the first and last time you make use of evm before trying to return it. You're returning a new, blank instance of `EmployeeViewModel()`.

Comment: no. evm gets populated during the XML Processing, and there are some DB actions that happen to add more details to the object. But even so, the ViewBag is also empty, which cannot be possible

Comment: Any chance you could show us the XML processing then?

Comment: I've updated the code. Although, I do not think that has anything to do with the question. Because the ViewBag appears before the XML processing